# How to make outbound calls in AsteriskNow using Asterisk AMI with Java

Tags: java, asterisk, asteriskami

I would like to initiate a call from extension number to another in LAN network. I have done this task through FreePBX GUI. Now I am trying to execute this task by using Asterisk AMI with Java code. Below Java code shows some exception while in debugging.

```
import java.io.IOException; 
import org.asteriskjava.manager.AuthenticationFailedException; 
import org.asteriskjava.manager.ManagerConnection; 
import org.asteriskjava.manager.ManagerConnectionFactory; 
import org.asteriskjava.manager.TimeoutException; 
import org.asteriskjava.manager.action.OriginateAction; 
import org.asteriskjava.manager.response.ManagerResponse; 

public class HelloManager 
{ 
private ManagerConnection managerConnection; 

public HelloManager() throws IOException 
{ 
ManagerConnectionFactory factory = new ManagerConnectionFactory( 
"192.168.68.173", "admin", "admin"); 

this.managerConnection = factory.createManagerConnection(); 
} 

public void run() throws IOException, AuthenticationFailedException, 
TimeoutException 
{ 
OriginateAction originateAction; 
ManagerResponse originateResponse; 

originateAction = new OriginateAction(); 
originateAction.setChannel("SIP/1010"); 
originateAction.setContext("default"); 
originateAction.setExten("2020"); 
originateAction.setPriority(new Integer(1)); 
originateAction.setTimeout(new Integer(30000)); 
// connect to Asterisk and log in 

managerConnection.login(); 

// send the originate action and wait for a maximum of 30 seconds for Asterisk 
// to send a reply 
originateResponse = managerConnection.sendAction(originateAction, 30000); 

// print out whether the originate succeeded or not 
System.out.println("Enter Response="+originateResponse.getResponse()); 

// and finally log off and disconnect 
managerConnection.logoff(); 
} 

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{ 
HelloManager helloManager; 

helloManager = new HelloManager(); 
helloManager.run(); 
} 
}
```

Exception:

```
run: 
Feb 06, 2014 4:04:16 PM org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl connect 
INFO: Connecting to 192.168.68.173:5038 
Feb 06, 2014 4:04:17 PM org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl setProtocolIdentifier 
INFO: Connected via Asterisk Call Manager/1.3 
Feb 06, 2014 4:04:17 PM org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl setProtocolIdentifier 
WARNING: Unsupported protocol version 'Asterisk Call Manager/1.3'. Use at your own risk. 
Feb 06, 2014 4:04:18 PM org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl disconnect 
INFO: Closing socket. 
Feb 06, 2014 4:04:18 PM org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerReaderImpl run 
INFO: Terminating reader thread: No more lines available: null 
Exception in thread "main" org.asteriskjava.manager.AuthenticationFailedException: Authentication failed 
at org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl.doLogin(ManagerConnectionImpl.java:578) 
at org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl.login(ManagerConnectionImpl.java:438)
at org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl.login(ManagerConnectionImpl.java:423)
at org.asteriskjava.manager.DefaultManagerConnection.login(DefaultManagerConnection.java:294)
at asteriskjtapi.HelloManager.run(HelloManager.java:49) 
at asteriskjtapi.HelloManager.main(HelloManager.java:67)
```

Note: 
Here I am using the credentials in FreePBX. Is this right one to access `ConnectionManager`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly paste your asterisk log while executing your java program

For getting asterisk log

```
 tail -f /var/log/asterisk/full
```

For checking the same from command line try this

```
 telnet 192.168.68.173  5038
 Action: Login
 Username: admin
 Secret: admin
```

if login sucessfull

```
 Action: Originate
 Channel: SIP/1010
 Exten: 2020
 Context: default
 Priority: 1
 Callerid: 1010
 Async: yes
```

Try this and let me know your outputs

Comment: I have tried with tenet, but it shows error:Authentication failed

Comment: Add your ip in permit list in managers.conf(/etc/asterisk/manager.conf)  ` [admin]
  secret = admin
  deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
  permit=xx.xx.xx.xx/255.255.255.0 (your connecting ip)`

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, you have to try to connect with asterisk through telnet.
2. If you get 'Login success' message, you can proceed with your programming. Otherwise if you get an 'Authentication failed' message, add your ip to the `permit` setting in `manager.conf`. Then save the changes.

   `permit:[your static ip]`
3. Try again with telnet